# Через какое время удалять файл с сервера после отправки письма с вложением?

Tags: php

Отправляю письмо с вложением. После отправки нужно удалить файл.
Можно ли удалять файл сразу, или нужно делать удаление через какое-то время?

Comment: При отправки письма, вложение посылается в теле самого письма. Следовательно, можете сразу удалить файл вложения.

Comment: @Reinq: если задачи по отправке выполняются в отдельном потоке, то не сразу.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin я что-то не совсем понял, что значит не сразу. Если использовать голый php, то вложенность будет собой представлять что-то вроде `$attachment =base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_path))` - следовательно, как только я с формировал эту переменную, исходный файл мне уже не требуется. Или я не прав?

Comment: @Reinq как только сформировали, не требуется, тут вы правы. Но у меня есть сомнения вот по какому поводу: когда и где она формируется? Если сразу отправлять очень много писем с вложениями, то в память одновременно загрузятся все файлы или будут грузиться и отправляться по очереди?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin ну как я понимаю, что если один и тот же файл нужен всем получателям - то как-только сформировали файл $attachment, можем теперь удалить сам файл, или после как отошлем всем. Если всем разные файлы, то по одному файлу формируем - удаляем - отсылаем. Причем можем сначала послать потом удалить файл. Как я понял, что хотел узнать автор вопроса - будет ли стучаться к этому файлу - почта получателя (gmail, mail, yandex). То ответ - не будет... можно удалять сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверняка письма вы отправляете в отдельном рабочем потоке. (Если нет — начните). В общем случае можно удалять файл сразу, как только код, отправляющий письмо, возвращает статус успешного завершения. То есть не тогда, когда задача загружена в рабочий поток, а тогда, когда он ее отработал. Можно добавлять удаление файла в конец задачи, например.

У вас есть уникальная возможность: вы можете сами запустить свой код и проверить. Напишите несколько юнит-тестов:

- Отправить письмо и удалить файл из задачи рабочего потока. Проверить, что дошло с файлом. Ожидаемый результат: дошло письмо с файлом.
- Отправить письмо и удалить файл из основного потока. Результат непредсказуем, но скорее всего будет ошибка.
- Сформировать письмо, удалить файл, отправить письмо. Ожидаемый результат: ошибка при отправке письма.
- Сформировать 1000 писем и отправить их одновременно. После этого сразу удалять файлы в основном потоке. Ожидаемый результат: ошибки при отправке части писем.
- Сформировать 1000 писем и отправить их одновременно. Удалять каждый файл тогда, когда рабочий поток завершает обработку письма. Ожидаемый результат: все письма отправляются, приходят и содержат файл.

Почему нужно в отдельном потоке: приложение не должно блокироваться на время отправки писем.